# Ionic 2: where to store app wide static strings and messages

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Where can I store app wide error messages or static strings? 
Currently I'm using **Providers**. Does we have any better way of doing this?

Comment: I would suggest application preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting one class for storing all your constants would definitely be an option I'd say.

However in case your speaking of error messages or generally text being rendered and displayed in your app, [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) would be an option. Even when you're not planning to publish your app for different languages, ng2-translate has several advantages, as you can store text for different parts of your app in different json files, allowing you to easily structure your text constants.

Also you do not need to load all your translations at once but have the possibility to require them when you really need them - so load the texts when you navigate to a particular route in your app instead of loading all of it on startup.

However - I'm assuming here, that you're speaking of messages or page content and not string constants you're using programmatically somewhere. In this case I'd say stick to your initial approach and export a class containing your constants to keep them in one place:

```ts
export class AppConstants {

  public static get API_ENDPOINT(): string 
  { 
    return 'http://some.url/api/'; 
  }

}
```